# Export form data on iPad into printable PDF

Tags: ios, forms, pdf, quartz-2d

I have an issue with "exporting" to PDF on an iPad.
My goal is, to take all the user data, a user has passed into the app for a form. The form itself is only available as a printed form, but I have the PDF as well. The thing is, after all the data has been given by the user, the output PDF I want to create for printing has to look completely like the printed version.

I have no idea of any "best practices" around how to accomplish this efficiently.
So my questions are:

1. Do I have to draw the form completely by myself and measure out all form field components on the printed form to draw them maybe with quartz2d?
2. Can I kind of parse the PDF I got already and read out all information to write a kind of script to transform the PDF into usable code?
3. What are best practices for filling out a form given in a paper version only to recreate the look of the original as close as possible? the look would be absolutely essential for the users of the app.

I do not have to read out form fields from the pdf. The only goal would be:

1. User taps on a print button in the app
2. from the user data provided by the app form a pdf should be created looking as close as possible compared to the printed version.

Thanks for any help on this

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are doing this for iOS5 they check Ray's article

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2

Comment: But this would require to build the complete pdf by hand, wouldn't it?

Comment: Another idea I had, was to convert the PDF to HTML, alter the tag content by my app and print the HTML as PDF again. This could be done maybe without showing the whole process to the user